# Thymeleaf Build-Up a String

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to create a string variable in thymeleaf by iterating through a loop and concatenating values into this string variable. Then i want to display this string in a `<span>` element. What i want to achieve can be written in java as follows:

```
String forDisplay = "";
foreach (MyObject o : myObjectCollection) {
   if (o.type == 1) { forDisplay += o.stringValue; }
}
```

Then in i want to put this in an html element like span. I know how to use:

```
<span th:each="o : ${objectCollection}" th:if="${o.type == 1}" th:text="${o.stringValue}"></span>
```

But this creates `<span>` for each of the elements that satisfy the condition. I just want to build-up my string in a `th` tag free section and then i just want to display my string in a single `<span>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmet, take a look at [Expression Utility Objects for Strings](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings), from Thymeleaf docs.

You have three methods for joining items:

```
${#strings.arrayJoin(namesArray,',')} // For Arrays
${#strings.listJoin(namesList,',')} // For Lists
${#strings.setJoin(namesSet,',')} // For Sets
```

These Utility Objects offers lots of cool methods for Aggregation, Calendars and etc.

Att

Comment: I already seen what you suggested; but i just wanted to know if it is possible with a jsp code block like option. Like `<% // Code Here %>` . I know this is somewhat against the philosophy of Thymeleaf but in some case I need this kind of free coding ability. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I join numbers into string using ", " as delimiter

```
<span th:each="instrumentDescriptor, iterStat : ${instrument.instrumentDescriptors}" th:text="!${iterStat.last} ? ${instrumentDescriptor.instrumentVersion} + ', ': ${instrumentDescriptor.instrumentVersion}"></span>
```

Comment: Again i would like to have a jsp code block like facility with thymeleaf. I see it is clearly not possible to have that kind of feature.